# Second SSH command is not executed on running multiple ssh shell commands via VBScript (objShell.Run)

Tags: ssh, vbscript

Invalid output is displayed on running multiple ssh shell commands via vbscript (QTP), whereas the same command is working fine with putty (unix server).

Line 1 - strShellCommand: The first ssh command connects to 'serverA', view the content of LogA.log and the second internal ssh command connects to 'serverB', view the content of LogB.log. 
Line 3: Runs the shell command

```
    'Build the command string for the Shell.Run command
1.  strShellCommand = ". $HOME/.profile;ssh -q user@serverA '. $HOME/.bash_profile; cd /apps/logs;cat LogA.log;ssh -q user@serverB " & """. $HOME/.bash_profile; cd /apps/logs;cat LogB.log;""" & "'"
2.  strCommand = "cmd /K CD " & PLINK_LOC & " & " & "plink.exe -ssh "& strUserName & "@" & strServerName & " -pw " & strPassword & " " & strShellCommand

    'Run the command and direct out put to temporary result file
3.  objShell.Run strCommand & ">" & strOutputLog & " 2>"& strErrorLog &" & exit", 0, blnCursorReturn

   Output:  
   Subversion client 1.6.11
   LogA Content
   Subversion client 1.6.11
   LogA Content
```

LogB content is not displayed in the output file, whereas the contents of LogA is repeated. It doesn't executes the second ssh command.

**Shell Command Works Fine in Putty** 
If I run the same script via putty or shell, it is working fine

```
ssh -q user@serverA '. $HOME/.bash_profile; cd /apps/logs;cat LogA.log;ssh -q user@serverB ". $HOME/.bash_profile; cd /apps/logs;cat LogB.log;"'    

Output:
Subversion client 1.6.11    
LogA Content
Subversion client 1.6.11
LogB Content
```

***Note:*** You can see the first ssh command uses single quote, whereas the second uses double quotes. This is how it works in putty.

I want to save both the logs in output file, so can you help to run it in single command via vbscript

Comment: Is blnCursorReturn set to True or false?

Comment: blnCursorReturn is set to True

Comment: Ok. My next question is why are you using the CD in your command line if you're just calling the one script?  CD doesn't seem necessary and maybe that's coming into play.  I'm not very familiar with command prompt syntax.

Comment: Its to change the path to plink location. Moreover, other commands are working fine except this scenario (multiple ssh commands in single line)